# Router event with switchMap duplicated output

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

I already solved my issue, but I would like to understand why this happens.

I'm banging my head reading and stuff but can't find why it's duplicating the output on the subscribe block.

Here is a stackblitz with the code

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-szwnz7

My train of thought is.

On that component, on every router event of type NavigationEnd I want to get the section id.

But nothing inside the event from the router interests me.
So I do a `switchMap`  with the `activatedRoute.queryParamMap` Observable, to inside the subscription block get the id number.

And everytime that I click between links it shows two console.logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's important to mention first that `queryParamMap` is derived from `queryParams`, which is a `BehaviorSubject`:

```js
function createActivatedRoute(c: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
  return new ActivatedRoute(
      new BehaviorSubject(c.url), new BehaviorSubject(c.params), new BehaviorSubject(c.queryParams),
      new BehaviorSubject(c.fragment), new BehaviorSubject(c.data), c.outlet, c.component, c);
}
```

[*Source*](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/create_router_state.ts#L76-L80)

And here is how `queryParamMap` is obtained:

```js
get queryParamMap(): ParamMap {
  if (!this._queryParamMap) {
    this._queryParamMap = convertToParamMap(this.queryParams);
  }
  return this._queryParamMap;
}
```

[*Source*](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/router_state.ts#L342-L347)

Under the hood, a [stream of transitions](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/router.ts#L439-L447%5C) is created. So, when you click a button, a **new transition** will be pushed into that stream, meaning that new routes will have to be **activated**:

```js
export const activateRoutes =
    (rootContexts: ChildrenOutletContexts, routeReuseStrategy: RouteReuseStrategy,
     forwardEvent: (evt: Event) => void): MonoTypeOperatorFunction<NavigationTransition> =>
        map(t => {
          new ActivateRoutes(
              routeReuseStrategy, t.targetRouterState!, t.currentRouterState, forwardEvent)
              .activate(rootContexts);
          return t;
        });
```

[*Source*](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/operators/activate_routes.ts#L21-L29)

This will cause `advanceActivatedRoute` to be called and eventually [this line](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/router_state.ts#L418) will be reached:

```js
(<any>route.queryParams).next(nextSnapshot.queryParams);
```

So this should be the first message logged to the console.

The next one is due to [`NavigationEnd` event](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/router.ts#L1091-L1106):

```js
(this.events as Subject<Event>)
              .next(new NavigationEnd(
                  t.id, this.serializeUrl(t.extractedUrl), this.serializeUrl(this.currentUrlTree)));
```

If you want to *visualize* this, you could open this [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/router-queryparams?file=src/app/app.component.ts), open dev tools and put some breakpoints:

- router_link.ts: 265 - when you click on a button
- activated_routes.ts: 25 - when a route is activated
- router.ts: 1062 - `NavigationEnd` event
- router_state.ts: 390 - `advanceActivatedRoute`'s body (during the route's activation process)
- app.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

Imagine that `this.route.queryParamMap` works as BehaviorSubject, that means that as soon as you subscribe to it you get the existing value and the new values arrive afterwards.

Now to explain your code, what happens when you click the link:

- `this.router.events` emits new NavigationEnd and you switch to `this.route.queryParamMap`
- `this.route.queryParamMap` has existing value and this existing value arrives in subscribe
- `this.route.queryParamMap` you are now subscribed to this Observable. New value arrives here too, because of navigation. `this.router.events` and `this.route.queryParamMap` are both independent Observables and on navigation both emits. So it's like race condition. You get first value due to `this.router.events` switched to `this.route.queryParamMap`'s existing value and the other coming directly from `this.route.queryParamMap`. And that's why another value arrives in subscribe.

Comment: Your explanation made me think of something, I made a modification on the stackblitz, it's nothing that works like BehaviorSubject, correct me if I'm wrong, but it duplicates because the `queryParamMap` subscriptions runs before the route change, because the query parameter `changed` then the route event fires, and run the new `queryParamMap` subscription, did I got right?

Comment: I think you are correct :D Also, `queryParamMap` does work like BehaviorSubject, subscribe to it via `setTimeout` in 1 second and you will see that it will emit value on subscription even though nothing happens. However, your assumption is still correct.